# React Native and RNFirebase iOS Release Builds Failing

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using Firebase via RNFirebase in React Native. I've gone through the steps here: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios.

Debug builds in the Simulator and to my device work just fine, but when I attempt to archive a Release build it fails with this error.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/rob5408/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-fggubxxejruuksefqfhjorhysodz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseAuth'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/rob5408/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-fggubxxejruuksefqfhjorhysodz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseCore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/rob5408/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-fggubxxejruuksefqfhjorhysodz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/rob5408/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-fggubxxejruuksefqfhjorhysodz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/rob5408/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-fggubxxejruuksefqfhjorhysodz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/nanopb'
ld: library not found for -lFirebaseAuth
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Also in the build logs I can see that the Debug config builds those targets, but they are not in the output for Release config builds. I get the feeling it has to do with building for all architectures, but don't know how where to start solving that. I just feel like I am poking around without a real strategy to solve it. Any ideas?

Some things I have tried...

- Using the Legacy Build System
- Removing `node_modules` and rerunning `npm install`
- Removing / adding the related pods
- Deintegerating and readding Cocoapods
- Clearing DerivedData
- Restarting my computer

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen when switching `use_frameworks!` off and on.

The solution was deleting FirebaseAuth and other libraries from the Build Setting - Other Linker Flags(OTHER_LDFLAGS)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I did actually try this before thinking `.framework`s would save me. Maybe it was a combo of this _and_ the Legacy Build System with a RN upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I got help from this PR: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter/pull/61

It was a combo of dropping down to the Legacy Build System in Xcode 10 and upgrading React Native to 0.57.2.